# php_printer.dll & IIS

Tags: php, iis

PHP 5.2.5
Microsoft IIS 6.0
Windows Server 2003 R2

I have just enabled php_printer.dll in my php.ini file, and it works correctly from the command line.  However, running the same commands within a script running on IIS gives me a "call to undefined function printer_open() ...".  My boss says we shouldn't have to restart IIS to get it to work, and is unwilling to try, because of the few mission-critical apps we have running on that server.  Is restarting IIS necessary, or should the commands be accessible from a script as well as from the command line?

Comment: How is php installed on the IIS? cgi, fastcgi, isapi?

Comment: it was installed through isapi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you ask on [serverfault](http://serverfault.com) whether a [IIS Process Recycling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525803.aspx) is advisable to reload php/isapi.